# Is this custom editing functionality in chrome header area hard to develop, any pointers at all?

Tags: content-query-web-part, branding

I am trying to develop web parts with custom functionality for editing for normal users. In the chrome bar there would be the same sort of controls as you see in the top right of your browser (except with a triangle instead of a line).

- Triangle is to minimise/restore (as in OOB, but with different display)
- Square is to maximize a new module type window, probably with an iFrame displayed in a module type view window with jQuery with an additional field to add the url to where it should go
- Cross is to delete web part

The functionality is required across a few different types of web parts including calendar, CBQ, Data View, CBQWP, and would ideally be a part of a custom chrome that would be added to them. I don't do back end code so I'm finding it hard to get my head around how someone would put together the functionality. Unless it's simple it won't be me writing this functionality. I have Enterprise 2010 for development, but the people using the control would only have foundation.

I'm basically after opinions about how this would be done. I think it should be a custom control written into the chrome, if that's possible. Does that seem feasible or is there a better way of doing it?

I would really appreciate any advise, even if it's just that it would be better to skin the existing chrome and leave the functionality as is. There's leeway with the functionality so at this stage it's deciding on how best to do it if it's possible or not too bother going down that route.

Thanks very much in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a worked solution for you but I do have a suggestion as to how I would perhaps approach this.

If you have ever looked into the SharePoint accessibility toolkit you will see that the a "ControlAdaptor" can be developed to override the rendered output of any particular .Net control. In the toolkit scenario this is used to replace the  outputs and replace them with more css friendly  elements.

Here's a link detailing how to achieve this: [Link Here](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/removing-web-parts-tables-sharepoint-2010/)

By adapting this technique you could intercept the rendering of the SharePoint webpart rendering and simply inject your own HTML elements and javascript into the webpart. That way you could add your custom triangle and associated callbacks as if they were part of the native webpart controls in the first place.

Comment: Thank you Brian. I hadn't looked at the accessibility toolkit in 2010. That sounds exactly what I'm after. It's all default functionality, just displayed in a different way so that should be perfect. I'll have a go today and let you know if it works.

Comment: @Dee: Good luck :-)